# How do I have a password field say "Password", which changes to password characters as you type?

Tags: html, passwords

It's a flat design, and I've kept the words "Username" and "Password" in the form items themselves. The dilemma is how do I get it to show "Password" but then as you type show the password characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `placeholder`:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
```

The placeholder text is shown as long as the input field is empty.

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks very much! :-)